# How do I put this UILabel code outside of my AppDelegate?

Tags: ios

I have started a new iOS "`Empty Application`"-template project. When I put this code inside of the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method, it works fine:

```
 CGRect frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 25);
 UILabel *helloLabel = [UILabel new];
 [helloLabel setFrame:frame];
 helloLabel.text = @"Hello iPhone!";  
 [self.window addSubview:helloLabel];
```

But what I really want to do is make an "addHello" class method in another class, so that what shows up in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` is just:

```
[MyOtherClass addHello];
```

This is what I've tried putting in the other class:

```
+ (void) addHello { 

CGRect frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 25);
UILabel *helloLabel = [UILabel new];
[helloLabel setFrame:frame];
helloLabel.text = @"Hello iPhone!";

UIWindow *window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
[window addSubview:helloLabel];

}
```

But that doesn't work. What am I supposed to do?

Comment: Show us your entire didFinishLaunchingWithOptions implementation.

Comment: The other stuff is boilerplate from the template:

    `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{  
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];  
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    
    
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}`

Comment: sorry about the formatting, couldn't figure out how to use mini-markdown to do it properly. The instructions on the 'learn more' page don't seem to work, particularly two spaces=linebreak.

}

Comment: That is what I suspected - you are not calling `makeKeyAndVisible` on your `window` before invoking your custom `addHello` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be that [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] is coming back nil in your code because you are calling your addHello method before the UIWindow's makeKeyAndVisible method has *not* been called. I wonder if this would work:

In your appDidFinishLaunching method:

```
[MyOtherClass addHelloWithWindow:self.window];
```

and then your MyOtherClass

```
+ (void) addHelloWithWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{ 
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 25);
    UILabel *helloLabel = [UILabel new];
    [helloLabel setFrame:frame];
    helloLabel.text = @"Hello iPhone!";
    [window addSubview:helloLabel];
}
```